# how to use host name in the place of ip address in the socket programming in java?

Tags: dns

I am using socket programming to connect two PCs in java through wi-fi. I used the ip address of the server at the client side. but the problem is that when the ip address of the server got changed then i have to change the ip address of server at client side. and when i use host name for connection nothing happens. is there any way to use static ip or any other solutions that can work to connect both of them which can work on any network. independent of ip address of the server.
please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Please post some example code and expand on your comment: *when i use host name for connection nothing happens*.

Comment: Do you mean like using DNS or dynamic DNS?

Comment: @DuncanJones Sir that means when i use InetAddress.getByHost("Rahul-PC")... it connected to the client locally but in the case of remote server, no connection was there..

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming at all -- I don't know why people have asked you for sample code, it's irrelevant. You need to set up a name service (i.e., "DNS") on your LAN. This is a service that lets computers find the addresses of other computers based on the name. If you need help seting this up, then you'll have better luck on our sysadmin/desktop support site. I'm recommending your  question be moved there.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill 
will this work upon wi-fi also??

Comment: Yes, doesn't matter what the physical link is; you're running TCP/IP over the wireless connection, same as if it were Ethernet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think there is a simple solution to your problem ...
you should get the ip address of your device by using Inetaddress.getbyName("user-pc").getHostAddress()

hope it will work for u...

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First of all If you are on LAN, then Any IP from Class A, B, C will suffice, But if you want it over the Internet, then you will have to be careful about the Private and Public IPs.

**2.** For **static IP** over internet you need to contact you **Internet Server Provider**, or you can try out some sites over the net that provides static ip based on your dynamic ips.

**3.** But if you want that due to the change in your server ip the client code need NOT be changed then you can do the following...

**-** Use the `Domain Name` of the Server **instead of IP, by using Domain Name Server.**

**-** Instead of storing the raw IP of the Server in the Client code, **use Some variable which gets the IP of the server from some** `file like the Property file, Database etc...`

Comment: You have to configure the DNS, then only you can use the domain name. so you can resolve the ip on the basis of its name. If you dont want to complicate it..just use a simple file, and let you Client program read the Server IP from there...so when any change take place,you client program need not to be changed..only the ip in the external file is to be changed..i have mentioned this above in my answer

Comment: Actually i am using android as my client and java class as my server. now without socket programming i can not connect my client to the PC's database or file. Your answer is best in the case when both of my class is in java.

Comment: Oh come on dear.... android client is to be written in java isnt it... And you can very much do this with socket programming.... And android code that performs the model part(Business Logic) is in java...

Comment: yes i am agree sir..
but according to you i have to connect to the file that containing sever's ip address... am i rite?
but according to me in android it is not possible to connect directly to the PC that containing that file or DB.

Comment: Dear store the file in the SDCard of mobile..... come on thats easy..and yes give the permission of ExternalStorage in the AndroidManifest.xml file